# Javascript error document.myform.mydiv is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript which is taking an input from a URL such as...

```
www.mydomain.com/?dropdown=Alpha
```

This will then pre-select Alpha from the dropdown box located at myform -> mydiv

```
function show(choice) {

  var success = -1;
  for (var i=0; i < document.myform.mydiv.length; i++) {
    if (document.myform.mydiv.options[i].text == choice) 
      success = [i];
  }
  document.myform.mydiv.selectedIndex=success;
} 
var choice = (location.href.split("?")[1] || '').split("=")[1];
```

Everything works fine apart from if you visit the url with no extension so www.mydomain.com - It then throws the following error...

```
document.myform.mydiv is undefined
```

The drop down html is...

```
<form name="myform">
  <select name="mydiv">
    <option value="1">Alpha</option>
    <option value="2">Beta</option>
    <option value="3">Gamma</option>
    <option value="4">Delta</option>
  </select>
</form>

 <script>
  show(choice);
  </script>
```

This is pretty self explanatory and I understand that this is because it is undefined, my question is how do I add a check to fix?

Comment: Please add your markup.

Comment: Do you mean `if (document.myform.myDiv) {}` ?

Comment: Your select's name is mydiv?

Comment: how is show() called? Where is it located?

Comment: I have updated the post with the details

Answer (score 1):

I think **your java script Function called before the Form Tag elements implementation**... So only this error occurs...

Try to **call that function from any one of the form element Events**... Then it will work...

Just like below...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var urlpath = "www.mydomain.com/?dropdown=Alpha"
var choice = (urlpath.split("?")[1] || '').split("=")[1];
function show()
{
var success = -1;
  for (var i=0; i < document.myform.mydiv.length; i++) {
    if (document.myform.mydiv.options[i].text== choice) 
      success = i;
  }
  document.myform.mydiv.selectedIndex=success;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
  <select name="mydiv" onchange="show();">

    <option value="2">Beta</option>
    <option value="3">Gamma</option>
    <option value="4">Delta</option>
    <option value="1">Alpha</option>
  </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, I was almost there!  Only issue now is that if for example the url and drop down contains a space it breaks.  So www.domain.com//dropdown=Beta Fish - Any ideas?

Comment: @fightstarr20 : i saw that your URL like  www.domain.com//dropdown=Beta Fish... So pls change that to  www.domain.com/?dropdown=Beta Fish ...  Now it will work.. See this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/62/